# Div to display if table of contents is not within scroll view

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a long HTML5 help document with a table of contents at the top. When the page is scrolled and the table is no longer visible, I want to display a floating div containing a link to the table:

```
<div id="DivTableOfContentsLink">
    <a href="#TableOfContents">
        Table of Contents
    </a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve this sing CSS only (without JavaScript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#DivTableOfContentsLink {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WE7n5/

you need set position to fixed so you can fixed it to the viewport (set right/left and bottom/top)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a way to handle hiding/displaying elements based on window location without javascript, but you could [try something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/r2UNC/).
Basically just have the title for table of contents double as a link and give it a position:fixed so when the user scrolls it remains at the top of the page.

css:

```
.toc-link {    
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

html:

```
<a class="toc-link" href="#toc">table of contents</a>
<ul id="toc">
    <li>chapter 1</li>
    <li>chapter 2</li>
    <li>chapter 3</li>
    <li>chapter 4</li>
    <li>chapter 5</li>
    <li>chapter 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from an article about a [floating menu with css only](http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm) from http://www.quackit.com/.

The relevant part is in the css `position:fixed` you can read all about **[positioning in the css 2.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolutely-positioned)**

Given this html

```
<div class="floating-menu">
    <h3>Floating Menu</h3>
    <a href="http://www.quackit.com/css/">CSS</a>
    <a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/">HTML</a>
    <a href="http://www.quackit.com/javascript/">JavaScript</a>
    <a href="http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/">ColdFusion</a>
    <a href="http://www.quackit.com/myspace/codes/">MySpace Codes</a>
</div>
```

And this css

```
div.floating-menu { position:fixed;
         background:#fff4c8;
         width:150px;
         z-index:100;
}
div.floating-menu a, div.floating-menu h3 {
       display:block;
       margin:0 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css (in <head> ... </head> section):

```
<style>
#toc {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color:#FFF;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#toc #full { display: none; }
#toc:hover #full{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
<BODY>
<UL>

<H2>Table of Contents - Demo</H2>

<UL>
<font size=2>
    <div id="toc"><font color=green><b>TABLE OF CONTENTS</b></font>
    <div id="full">
        <ul>
        <li> <a href="ml-implementation_notes.html#Activation%20Functions">Activation Functions</a>&nbsp; [separate file]<br>
        <li> <a href="#Adversarial Networks">Adversarial Networks | Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN)</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#AI">AI: Artificial Intelligence</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#Applied ML">Applied ML</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#Approach, Algorithms, Advice">Approach, Algorithms, Advice</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#Architectures - General">Architectures - General</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#Architectures - RBM">Architectures - RBM | DBN | MLP | Energy-Based Models ...</a><br>
        [ ... SNIP! ... ]
        <li> <a href="files/datasci.html#Visualization">Visualization</a>  &nbsp; [separate file]<br>
        <li> <a href="#VQA">Visual Question-Answering [VQA]</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#VSM - GloVe; word2vec | doc2vec | Gensim | paragraph2vec | ...">VSM - GloVe; word2vec | doc2vec | Gensim | paragraph2vec | ...</a><br>
        <li> <a href="#Web-Based Implementations">Web-Based Implementations</a><br>
        </ul>
    </div></div>
</UL>
</font>

<p>
This is just a demo, hence the TOC links will <i>not</i> work!

If the TOC length exceeds the page height, it will scroll via this CSS code:

    <p>
    <div><pre><font size=2>        ...
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        ...</font></pre></div>

<p>
Note: need <i>both</i> of those lines!
<br><br>
</UL>
</BODY>
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/zitogixexa/edit?output

example (animated GIF):[image: animated GIF]